# Pandas Groupby- Adding sequential elements based on group changes

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a df like this.

[image]

I want to group by A and then B and get the sequence column such that every time when subgroup B changes the first element of next subgroup is ((x+8)-(x%8))+1 of the previous subgroups count. eg., B1's count is 5 and hence the first element of B2 should be ((5+8)-(5%8))+1 =9 and then the sequence continues for that group.

And once the group A changes the sequence should start from 1 again.

This is the ouput needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the logic for calculating each change in the 'B group', so I didn't complete it until the end. If you can use this, please use it as a reference. Please comment if it doesn't work at all. Delete.

```
df['flg'] = 1
df['a_seq'] = df.groupby('A')['flg'].agg('cumsum')
df['b_seq'] = df.groupby('B')['flg'].agg('cumsum')

df['Sequence'] = np.where(df['b_seq'] == df['a_seq'], df['b_seq'], df['a_seq'].apply(lambda x: ((x+8)-(x%8))+1))

    A   B   flg a_seq   b_seq   Sequence
0   1   B1  1   1   1   1
1   1   B1  1   2   2   2
2   1   B1  1   3   3   3
3   1   B2  1   4   1   9
4   1   B2  1   5   2   9
5   1   B2  1   6   3   9
6   1   B2  1   7   4   9
7   2   B3  1   1   1   1
8   2   B3  1   2   2   2
9   2   B3  1   3   3   3
10  2   B3  1   4   4   4
11  2   B3  1   5   5   5
12  2   B4  1   6   1   9
13  2   B4  1   7   2   9
14  2   B5  1   8   1   17
15  2   B5  1   9   2   17
16  2   B5  1   10  3   17
17  2   B5  1   11  4   17
18  2   B5  1   12  5   17
19  2   B6  1   13  1   17
20  2   B6  1   14  2   17
```